# 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less' wasn't found

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gulp, less

I am writing task for my application using gulp to minify css

```
gulp.task('handle-styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/styles/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
})
```

getting error as :

```
[14:46:54] Starting 'handle-styles'...
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less' wasn't found.
```

and showing the error is in main.less file line no.2

Main.less:

```
@import 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome';
@fa-font-path: 'font-awesome/fonts';    

@import '~bootstrap/less/bootstrap';
@icon-font-path: '~bootstrap/fonts/';
```

Font-awesome version is 4.2.0

Any help

following are screenshots:
    [image: pic1]
    [image: pic2]
    [image: pic3]
    [image: pic4]

Comment: what does the error say in your Main.less ? Also can you show your bower.json

Comment: 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less' wasn't found

Comment: gulp-less unable to recognize @import as I tried running the task commenting import statement of font awesome ...again I got same error with bootstrap import statement

Comment: is it `@import 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome'` or `@import 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less'` ? - There is no `.less` extension for the font-awesome file name. Same goes with bootstrap

Comment: Use the [`path` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less#options) to specify location of imported files.

Comment: Yeah I removed the extension and tried, but I am getting same error

Comment: I meant add the extension. Could you also give us the directory structure of your project. That would give us the solution. You could update it in the question

Comment: It is working, but I need to keep on adding all my imports. Is there a way to do it much simple ?@SvenSchoenung

Comment: Notice the error message lists all the dirs it tried and there's no `bower_components` among them. And indeed, I don't see the dir mentioned in your `gulp` task. So how are you expecting it to be found at all? So as suggested above simply add `bower_components` via `path` option.